# Laravel 8 UniSharp File Manager 3 - image uploaded but not showing

Tags: laravel-5, unisharp-file-manager

When I upload some files with LFM, the images are uploaded in a new folder created in storage/app/public/photos/shares and thumbnails in a nested folder thumbs.  BUT the images thumbnails are not showing in the FM, only the filenames under a blank image.

1/ How can I fix that?

2/ Under the images there is a little blue box with number 1 inside . What is that?  I can I get rid of it?

3/ I also find strange that the images are stored in a "shared" folder although this is set to false in the /config/lfm.php.  Do I have to edit unisharp/laravel-filemanager/src/config/lfm.php as well?  Or should I delete the one in /config?

```
'allow_shared_folder'      => false,
'shared_folder_name'       => 'shares',
```

4/ I also do not want that location for the upload.  Instead I want the images stored in /public/images/uploads and same for the files into /public/files/uploads.  Where do I change these paths?

Answer (score 0):

change your `APP_URL="localhost"` to your port (for ex : `APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000`)

Answer (score 0):

In config folder
open filesystem.php

replace './storage' instead of  storage_path('app/public')